# Can SQLite and Qt be bundled into my program?

Tags: java, c++, c, qt, sqlite

I am working on project that uses SQLite as the DB and I intend to do the coding C++/JAVA with Qt.

Does the user who is going to run my program need to have pre-installed SQLite DB and Qt libraries?

Can I include all these in the zip file of my program? (assume that the program doesn't have to be explicitly installed, just a double click will open it)

Comment: Did you read http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html ? You can include the sqlite plugin as described there (for other plugins).